# WordPress Custom Permalink Structure for: Pages, Posts and Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to set a custom permalink structure for a custom post type based on a custom parent/child taxonomy. I've managed to achieve the thing but I broke the permalink structure for pages and posts.

I've accomplisged the following:

mysite.com/taxonomy_parent/taxonomy_child/postname

In other words, I've remove the taxonomy slug and the URL show the correct hierarchical order. First, I set the 'rewrite' arg when registering the custom taxonomy and the custom post-type:

for the custom taxonomy:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
```

for the post type:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%mytaxonomy%', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
```

Then I added the following code in order to get support to show the parent/child taxonomy in the URL.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?myposttype=$matches[3]';
    $newRules['(.+)/?$']           = 'index.php?mytaxonomy=$matches[1]';
    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'myposttype')
        return $link;
    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'mytaxonomy'))
    {
        $link = str_replace('%mytaxonomy%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'mytaxonomy', false, '/', true), $link);
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {    
    $chain = '';   
    $parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);
    if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
        return $parent;
    }
    if ($nicename)    
        $name = $parent -> slug;        
else    
        $name = $parent -> name;
    if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {    
        $visited[] = $parent -> parent;    
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);
    }
    if ($link) {
        // nothing, can't get this working :(
    } else    
        $chain .= $name . $separator;
    return $chain;    
}
```

This works great but there's a conflict with the custom permalink for the posts and pages. I need to configure that too. Actually, I need "mysite.com/blog/category/postname" and "mysite.com/pagename". As easy as to set a custom permalink like that "/%category%/%postname%/" works properly but a 404 error page is returned when the necessary current config I've explained is set in my functions.php

I suppose there's a problem with rewrite_rules but don't know how to fix it or how to set new rules to support my custom post_type/custom taxonomy permalink structure at the same time the custom permalink structure for posts and pages works properly.